# File Sharing using JMS & ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am transferring a file from producer to consumer using JMS through ActiveMQ using BytesMessage. My requirement is to know the File Name at the consumer side. Is there any way to achive this.

Answer (score 1):

You could add file name into JMS header:

```
// create JMS connection and session
ByteMessage m = session.createObjectMessage();
// read file into buffer
m.writeBytes(buf, 0, len);
// set file name
m.setStringProperty("fileName", fileName);
```

I suppose there is a limit on property size, but I think this is vendor-specific.